Understanding Half-Gates for Garbled Circuits
Currently I am reading though Two Halves Make a Whole and understand the basics of generator half-gate and evaluator half-gate.
The generator half-gate can be used when the garbler knows the input to its value magically.
The evaluator half-gate can be used when the evaluator knows its value magically.
This seems great for input AND gates but I still don't understand how we can combine these to be useful for AND gates which are not input AND gates?
From the paper (and my understanding) when we want to compute
c = a ^ b
where we don't know a and b we can do
c = (a ^ r) + (a ^ (r + b))  (on page 7)
and since r is technically randomly sampled we can compute
(a ^ r) using the generator half-gate since we know r.
And we can compute (a ^ (r + b)) using evaluator half-gate as long as we let the evaluator learn (r + b).
How do we let the evaluator learn (r + b) when b is the plain bit value?? I thought we were supposed to be working with labels not the plain values?
Is there any example for a shallow circuit where we can see how these half gates are actually being used? As currently I am having difficulty understanding how we can use half gates for AND gates that are not input AND gates.

FYI, $\LaTeX$/MathJax is enabled on our site.
